# Get nested element by name

Tags: javascript

I have a table of elements like this:

```
<tr id="elementId">
<img name="img" src=""/><br/>
<input name="text" type="text"/><br/>
<input name="button" type="button"/><br/>
</tr>
```

Each element is exactly the same, except of its id.
I try to update the elements with javascript, but I have no clue how to get the child nodes by their name.

My code:

```
//get element
var element = list.rows[i];
//update nodes
element.getElementByName("img")[0].src = someImg;
element.getElementByName("text")[0].value = someText;
element.getElementByName("button")[0].value = someOtherText;
```

The code doesn't work, because `element` has no function `getElementByName`.

Is there any other way to get the nodes by their name?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not also giving them an id and not using 'getElementById()'?

Comment: Why don't you use jquery? It will make it simpler.

Comment: Just give id to all and use element.getElementById();

Comment: @NeilMunro I can't give them ids because there are a lot of these elements. If I give them ids there will be multiple same ids

Comment: @NeilMunro — Given that it is in a table row, presumably because it would have all the usual problems of generating duplicate IDs and working around that would be just as much, if not more, effort than using the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element.querySelector('[name="thename"]')` or `element.querySelectorAll('[name=2thename"]')`

Answer (score 3):

The function is `getElementsByName`. Elements is plural.

Note that it returns an array-like HTML Collection, so you'll need to grab the first item off it too (with `[0]`).

Additionally, you might find that your elements aren't actually in your table row as you are missing table cells. Validate your markup: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0):

In order to select all alements with a tagname in the whole document you may use

```
listElements = document.getElementsByTagName();
```

Inside a certain element, you may use

```
selectedElement = element.getElementsByTagName();
```

Notice this functions returns an array with the elements selected. If there is only one element, it will be in

```
listElements[0]
```

in the first case, or

```
selectedElement[0]
```

in the second.